# Push-Location command in PowerShell doesn't recognize newly created drive names

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm having some issues with creating new drive labels through a script.  I've isolated the problem down to a few lines to reproduce the issue.

First, create a file called `Test.ps1`:

```
New-PSDrive -name Foo -PSProvider FileSystem -root "C:\Code"
Set-Location Foo:\
```

You can change `C:\Code` with any directory that exists.

Next, on the PowerShell command line, run:

```
.\Test.ps1
```

Followed by:

```
Push-Location Foo:\
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Push-Location : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'Foo' does not exist.
At line:1 char:14
+ Push-Location <<<<  Foo:\
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Foo:String) [Push-Location], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PushLocationCommand
```

[image]

It's as if the `Push-Location` stack caches all the drive labels when the shell is initialized, and the `New-PSDrive` command doesn't update that cache.  Is there any way to work around this bug, or force this *stale data* to update?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a called script or function is run in a new scope, so variables, functions, and drives defined in that scope are not accessible in outer scopes unless they are explicitly added to the global scope.

You can explicitly add the drive to the global scope, as you've mentioned, with the Scope parameter on `New-PSDrive`. There are several cmdlets and functions that have a scope parameter. Use `get-help * -Parameter Scope` to find them.

Another option is to run the script in the current scope using the dot source notation:

```
. .\Test.ps1
```

Comment: Yup, the function itself is actually defined within a module (`.psm1` file) and loaded using `Import-Module`.  My solution seems to work great.  It's a bit weird you can create a PSDrive within a local scope, change to that drive, and when the script exits, the drive exists in this kinda limbo state.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

```
New-PSDrive -name Foo -PSProvider FileSystem -root "C:\Code" -Scope Global
```

Setting `-Scope Global` fixes the problem.